# How can I view the differences between two DLLs?

Tags: dll, diff, visual-c++, disassembly

Is there a way to view the difference between two binary DLL files?  I have PDBs for both.

Ideally I'd like to see:

- What functions have been added
- What functions have been removed
- What functions have been modified (with a diff of the disassembly)
- What other entries (static variables, resources, etc) have been added/removed/modified

---

Note: this is different from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590863/tool-to-compare-dlls-and-disassemble-the-differences) as I am dealing with native DLLs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to compare executable files, you have a couple of alternatives:

- Bindiff: it's a commercial extension for the commercial disassembler IDA Pro. It's a de-facto tool for reverse engineering. According to the vendor description, it allows you to:

  - Identify identical and similar functions in different binaries
  - Port function names, anterior and posterior comment lines, standard comments and local names from one disassembly to the other
  - Detect & highlight changes between two variants of the same function

http://www.zynamics.com/bindiff.html

- You still have a free alternative: PatchDiff. As Bindiff, it's also a plugin for IDA Pro. According to the developer, Patchdiff can perform the following tasks:

  - Display the list of identical functions
  - Display the list of matched functions
  - Display the list of unmatched functions (with the CRC)
  - Display a flow graph for identical and matched functions

http://cgi.tenablesecurity.com/tenable/patchdiff.php

Comment: IDA Pro + PatchDiff looks perfect.

Answer (score 1):

A "low tech" approach (no disassembly) would be to use `DUMPBIN /ALL` (or another switch, depending on what exactly you want to know) on the DLLs and do a text compare on the result.